# Бесконечный цикл while в Python

Tags: python

```py
category = input('Категория (stop - завершить):')
while category != 'stop':
    if category == 'мясные изделия':
        print('Скидка 10%.')
    elif category == 'напитки':
        print('Скидка 30%.')
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
category = input('Введите категорию продуктов:')
```

Ввожу категорию - получаю бесконечный цикл (просто бесконечно печатает какой-либо принт). Я новичок, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну собственно в показанном коде нет никаких причин, которые могли бы прервать эту бесконечность

Comment: Какое значение у переменной `category` _перед_ циклом?  И почему ввод в эту переменную выполняется _вне_ цикла?

Answer (score 2):

Эта часть вашего кода

```
while category != 'stop':
    if category == 'мясные изделия':
        print('Скидка 10%.')
    elif category == 'напитки':
        print('Скидка 30%.')
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
```

повторяется, пока в переменной `category` не будет значение `'stop'`.

Повторяется, повторяется, но значение переменной `category` не изменяется, потому что ваша следующая команда

```
category = input('Введите категорию продуктов:')
```

**ждет**, пока ваш цикл `while` **не окончится**, чтобы она могла заработать. И — как я уже объяснил — он не окончится **никогда**.

Нужно *перенести эту команду в цикл*, чтобы она выполнилась, и чтобы вы могли в ответе на вопрос `Введите категорию продуктов:` ответить `stop`.

```
category = input('Категория (stop - завершить): ')
while category != 'stop':
    if category == 'мясные изделия':
        print('Скидка 10%.')
    elif category == 'напитки':
        print('Скидка 30%.')
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
    category = input('Категория (stop - завершить): ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Подвинти `category = input('Введите категорию продуктов:')` в цикл, будет тогда каждый раз спрашивать параметры для if. Или какая должна быть логика?

```
while True:
    category = input('Введите категорию продуктов:')
    if category == 'мясные изделия':
        print('Скидка 10%.')
    elif category == 'напитки':
        print('Скидка 30%.')
    elif category == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
category = input('Категория (stop - завершить):')
while category != 'stop':
    if category == 'мясные изделия':
        print('Скидка 10%.')
    elif category == 'напитки':
        print('Скидка 30%.')
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
    category = input('Введите категорию продуктов(stop - завершить):')
```

Может так.

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется, чтобы программа выполнялась один раз, то это можно сделать так:

```
category = input("Введите категорию продуктов:")
while category != "stop":
    if category == "мясные изделия":
        print("Скидка 10%.")
        break
    elif category == "напитки":
        print("Скидка 30%.")
        break
    else:
        print("Скидок нет.")
        break
```

Если требуется задавать вопрос несколько раз, то решение этой проблемы описали выше.

Comment: А цикл тогда зачем?)))

Comment: Ну я просто взял его код, как я понял он не понимает как выйти из цикла, если я правильно понял вопрос. По сути он тут не нужен

Comment: Почему не нужен? А если мы хотим узнать скидку для нескольких категорий?

Comment: @NowhereMan, простите, не заметил когда выкладывал ответ

Comment: Сделать цикл, в котором _не меняется_ значение переменной, и вывалиться из цикла по `break` после первой же итерации.. Зачем?!

Comment: Это своеобразный if. Ввел stop и код внутри не отработал))

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз категорию нужно спрашивать у пользователя. Для этого можно сделать бесконечный цикл и внутри писать `input`. Такой вариант хорош и его предложил [Amgarak](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/562052/amgarak). Я могу предложить вот такое решение: поместить `input` внутрь условия `while`, используя "моржовый" оператор

```
while answer:= input('Введите категорию - (stop-выход)').lower(): 
    if answer == 'мясные изделия': 
        print('Скидка n %')
    elif answer == 'stop': 
        break
    else:
        print('Скидок нет.')
```

Comment: Проверку на “stop” тоже можно поместить следом за моржовым оператором, тогда избавимся от лишней конструкции “elif” - “break”.